# when does Android 4.5 comes and will my phone get update?

Tags: android-versions

I got LG OPTIMUS G PRO (F240L)
and I wanna know , will it get OTA 4.5 updates?

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.5 ([Android L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_L)?) is not yet released.

Google has not yet announced the release date.

If you are a developer, you can take a look at [Android L Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html).

Once the official Android L is released, your OEM (LG) may think of porting it to your phone model (LG Optimus G Pro), and after the porting is completed and tested, LG may provide the OTA update.

Comment: well I can look up the Developer's preview.. I will try to install  Android L on my G pro device

Comment: @AtharRajpoot - You can not deploy developer preview in your device. It is only permitted to Nexus devices. See the developer page again.

Comment: Mani is correct @AtharRajpoot. +1

Comment: well i seen that.. I guess i must wait.. or i should buy nexus device